# poLCA ALERT values that are not positive integers

Tags: class, cluster-computing, alert, analysis

everybody.

I am trying to run an LCA using poLCA package. I have six categorical variables, from which one is binary (gender) and the other ones range from 3 to 7 categories. I keep getting an alert message as follows:

> ALERT: some manifest variables contain values that are not
>       positive integers. For poLCA to run, please recode categorical
>       outcome variables to increment from 1 to the maximum number of
>       outcome categories for each variable.

I applied as.integer() and I tried recoding replacing level 0, but it is still not working. Any ideas on how this could be, please? Thank you in advance!

Below, my code:

```
f<- with(mydata, cbind(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)~outcome)
LCA<-poLCA(f, data, nclass=6, nrep=50)
summary(LCA)
```

Output:

> ALERT: some manifest variables contain values that are not
>       positive integers. For poLCA to run, please recode categorical
>       outcome variables to increment from 1 to the maximum number of
>       outcome categories for each variable.

Answer (score 1):

Manifest values needs to be an integer starting from 1 and not 0, hence it shows that error.
You need to add 1 to your dataset.

```
data=data+1;
```

Now run the function :)

Answer (score 1):

For continuous variables (if you have in your dataset, you can round them to nearest digit)

round(mydata, digits=0)

Comment: Just to thank you, even if its too late... Sorry I missed this!