# poLCA ALERT values are not positive integers

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I am trying to run a Latent Class Analysis in R using the package poLCA  on the four variables optimism, innovation, discomfort and insecurity from the Technology Readiness Index. The dataset we collected contains ratings from 183 participants on optimism, innovation, insecurity and comfort ranging from 1 (disagree) to 5 (agree). The aim is to uncover clusters in the ratings to create different technology readiness segments / categories.

Following [this tutorial from Princeton University](https://pop.princeton.edu/events/2020/latent-class-analysis-using-r), the code is as follows:

```
f1  <- as.formula(cbind(Opt,Inno, Dis, Ins) ~ 1)
LCA <- poLCA(f1, data=dat, nclass=2)
```

I get the error message:

```
    positive integers. For poLCA to run, please recode categorical
    outcome variables to increment from 1 to the maximum number of
    outcome categories for each variable.
```

The data does not contain any negative integers an no [missing values](https://rdrr.io/cran/poLCA/src/R/poLCA.R) .

```
> min(dat$Ins)
[1] 1.5
> min(dat$Opt)
[1] 2
> min(dat$Inno)
[1] 1.25
> min(dat$Dis)
[1] 1.75

> sum(is.na(dat[, 102:105]))
[1] 0
```

In my desperation, I tried i) [adding 1 to the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008147/polca-alert-values-that-are-not-positive-integers) and ii) converting the variables to a factor format. The problem persists.

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message was data aggregation resulting in non-integers. There are two ways to fix this:
a) including the all the 16 original items (4 for optimism, innovation, discomfort, insecurity each). This only works when the dataset is large enough.
b) rounding the aggregated ratings with
`round(dat$ino, digits = 0)`